# How to read associative array sent from cloud code in iOS sdk?

Tags: ios, parse-platform, cloud

I have a cloud code function on Parse.com and I receive following response, can anybody please tell me how to read it in iOS code ?

```
{"result":[{"week":1,"avg":50.5},{"week":2,"avg":0},{"week":3,"avg":0},{"week":4,"avg":29},{"week":5,"avg":0},{"week":6,"avg":0},{"week":7,"avg":0}]}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reply from cloudcode are already decoded into NSDictionary / NSArray compatible object or  possibly mapped subclasses of PFObject if you have registered them. 
Do `NSLog(@"reply from parse : %@",reply);`  in cloud function block to see that data are already parsed.
You should be then able to process data like

```
for (NSDictionary * currentWeek in reply)  {
....
}
```